# storage permission in android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am developing a small application that using the storage (read & write)
I implemented the read & write with different requests code, one for read and the other for write.
My question is it required to have both requests and not only using just one for storage in general?
Also I noticed when going to permission console, I only have one option to enable/disable the storage permission(both read & write and not separately as I originally thought).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to ask for the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission if you already ask for the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, since the permission to read is automatically granted if you can write.

Comment: You are correct, the problem is sometimes when the permission is disabled and I need to write first before read I need to ask for write permissions, and in some other scenarios (when the permission is down) I need to read before write

Comment: @visionixvisionix I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but generally I would just forget about the read permission and use only the write permission anyway.

Comment: I have implemented an export and import capabilities. the user has several items that can be exported (need read permission), while in import (I would need the write permission). the scenario is if the user goes straight to import or export without any storage permissions.